# iOS Git and Cocoapods - how to commit customization to a module added through Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, version-control, cocoapods

I'm working with `AFNetworking` and need to modify `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` to use custom user-agent string.

I made the required changes on my machine, but the Pods directory is not versioned. As such, I cannot just commit my changes, and other devs cant see the fix. Even if they reapply the fix manually on their machine, next time someone runs `pod install`, they will lose the changes.

**How can I modify my git repository or podfile to make sure that my fix to AFHTTPRequestSerializer is saved?**

Answer (score 1):

The intended process here is to fork `AFNetworking` and point your pod file to your fork, which you can modify at will. Then as `AFNetworking` gets updated, you can easily pull those changes into your own repo with a pull-request, or just a merge.

Answer (score 1):

First you need your changes to be saved on repository (a fork of AFNetworking e.g.). Make a branch with your changes to `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`. Now in pod file add this line:

```
pod '<--componentName>', :git => 'https://github.com/path/to-component.git', :branch => '<--branch-name-->'
```

Now every time you do pod update cocoa pods will take your branch as the last release.